# Simple question about the lunarlander example

Tags: java, android, performance, graphics, drawing

I am basing my game off the lunarlander example. This is the run loop I am using (very similar to what is used in lunarlander). I am getting considerable performance issues associated with my drawing, even if I draw almost nothing.

I noticed the below method. Why is the canvas being created and set to null each cycle?

```
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        while (mRun) 
        {
            Canvas c = null;
            try 
            {
                c = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();//null
                synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) 
                {
                    updatePhysics();
                    doDraw(c);
                }
            } finally 
            {
                // do this in a finally so that if an exception is thrown
                // during the above, we don't leave the Surface in an
                // inconsistent state
                if (c != null) 
                {
                    mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Most of the times I have read anything about canvases it is more along the lines of:

```
mField = new Bitmap(...dimensions...);
Canvas c = new Canvas(mField);
```

My question is: why is Google's example done that way (null canvas), what are the benefits of this, and is there a faster way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example your making a new canvas indeed. But when you say

> Why is the canvas being created and set to null each cycle?

I don't think that is what happens. There is 'a' canvas (variable) created, and set to null for starters. THen this is called

```
c = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
```

Which returns a canvas that is used. (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.html#lockCanvas%28%29 )

There is no 'new canvas' created as you seem to suggest. If something goes awry the c stays null, and you can check for that. If it's not null you do your unlock.

Comment: Ah, I am pretty new to this if you couldn't tell. With the lockCanvas method, would there be any performance benefit to specifying a dirty rectangle? Also, do you need to specify the size of the canvas anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not doing your drawing in a separate Thread as they do in the Lunar example.

Comment: Create a Thread that will have a reference to the Holder or the surface. Starts it. In the Run() method add your drawings. Do not forget to not start your thread before the surface is shown, else you will have a null canvas. To be sure, just start the Thread using a callback on the holder or in the onSurfaceCreate method.